# Play Iteratee throttling

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, loops

I'm writing a streaming web radio framework using scala and Play. I'm relying on Iteratees for the actual streaming, but I'm running into an issue trying to prevent a greedy client from downloading data too quickly, and consuming the stream for all the clients. To do so I've been  trying to create an Enumeratee that will throttle how quickly the Enumerator produces data. Here's what my Enumeratee looks like

```
val throttlingIteratee = Iteratee.foldM[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]](new Array[Byte](0)) {
(result, chunk) => 
  val prom = Promise[Array[Byte]]()
  timer.schedule(new TimerTask{
    def run() = prom.success(result ++ chunk)
    },1000)
  prom.future    
}

private val chunker = Enumeratee.grouped(  
    Traversable.take[Array[Byte]](31792) &>> throttlingIteratee  
)
```

The idea is that I use the timer task to create a throttlingIteratee and pair that with the Enumeratee.grouped function. This seems to work fairly well, but I'm having trouble figuring out what value to use for the chunk size. I want to have this produce chunks at about the same rate as the audio plays. My audio file is encoded at 82kpbs, and I've tried to calculate that in terms of bytes, but the values I come up with seem to be too small, and the audio plays faster than the data is streamed.

My question is two fold. Is the basic approach I have in place a good one? And if it is, how do I go about setting the chunk size in terms of the audio file's bit rate.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- 1 kbps = 1000 bits per second = 125 bytes per second. So in your case 10,250 bytes per second.
- I don't see any problem with your code. I assume you stripped out the code to handle failures for clarity.
- I don't know your use case, but I would assume that setting this type of throttling can be more easily done in a proxy or a web server instead of in your code.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't touched this in a while, but I'll try to dig up my old code and test out your numbers this weekend so I can accept this answer